# Azure Functions Node.js typescript global variable

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger, azure-functions-node.js

I have some node.js Azure Functions (httptriggers) coded with Typescript that I secure with a jwt token.  After validating my token at the beginning of the funtion, I'd like to store it globally so I can use it in all my child functions.  But I'd like my token to be valid only for the current Invokation Context.  I don't want to pass the token as parameter to any function that may need it.

Example:

```
// I'd like to store it like that, but that isn't thread safe, other user may get the same token
export let globalToken : any;

export async function users(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {

   globalToken = validateToken(request);

   if(request.method === "GET"){
      return { jsonBody: getUsers() };
   }

}


//### In user.service.ts file ###

export const getUsers = () => {

   // so I can use it everywhere like that, without passing it in parameter every time
   return usersData.filter(u => u.userId === globalToken.userId)

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to achieve is doable without some sort of IoC that supports scoped lifecycles. Something like [InversifyJS](https://inversify.io) do support scoped lifecycles. I haven't used InversifyJS for Azure Functions before, though, and the samples I could find with my limited Google-foo skills seem experimental at best:

- [mgomezarr's example on github](https://github.com/mgomezarr/AzureFunctions-Nodejs-DependencyInjection)
- [jakkaj/Jordan Knight's take, also available on github](https://github.com/jakkaj/EnterpriseAzureFunctions)

But the gist of it would be a service which is registered as scoped, and have a public property (either directly or via getter/setter methods) that can store your information (see [`inRequestScope`](https://doc.inversify.cloud/en/scope#about-inrequestscope) for registering scoped services in InversifyJS).

Since the http trigger would be the root of the dependency graph in our case, and have the scoped service as dependency, any other dependencies we inject/resolve from our http trigger should share the same instance. Using the explanation on the about page for `inRequestScope` (the A -> B -> R, -> C -> R sample), "A" for us would be the HttpTrigger, and "R" would be the scoped service, "B" and/or "C" would be other services, like your `user.service.ts`.

I will note that this seems slightly excessive to implement, if all you want to achieve is to avoid having to parse values between methods (personal take). However, if your project is *really* large, and you have a lot of dependencies, and some of the values you have to parse around is for a dependency several layers deep, then I can understand why you want to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, thats what my web digging ended up with too.  Would've really liked to see a request scoped varible natively

Comment: Come to think of it, I thought of C#'s `AsyncLocal` that can transport state between methods/functions, in an async control flow, while being thread safe. [Found this](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/async-local-storage) on Google. I didn't look too much into it, but if it works the same as `AsyncLocal` in C#, you should be able to just have a static reference to a "singleton"-instance of your `AsyncLocalStorage`, in case you want to avoid IoC/DI. Then simply access the static instance from your services and access the value. From your HttpTrigger, set the value before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the context.bindingData object to store and retrieve data within the context of the current function invocation. let me give you a modified code.

```js
export async function users(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
   const globalToken = validateToken(request);

   // u can store the token in the context.bindingData for the current invocation
   context.bindingData.globalToken = globalToken;

   if (request.method === "GET") {
      return { jsonBody: getUsers(context) };
   }
}

export const getUsers = (context: InvocationContext) => {
   // Retrieve the token from the context.bindingData
   const globalToken = context.bindingData.globalToken;

   // Use th token as wanted
   return usersData.filter(u => u.userId === globalToken.userId);
};
```

Comment: Yes but that doesn’t really help because I need to pass the context as a parameter.  I’m looking for a way to access my token globally, without passing it along everywhere in my service layer and then repository layer in each and every function.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I don't think this is actually a good implementation from a security perspective. Storing a JWT is the same as storing a username/password. Better is to develop an impersonation scheme that allows all the functions invoked for a given JWT to impersonate a known identity related to some claim(s) in the JWT with the necessary permissions.

Use a key vault. Allow your initial function to store it there as a secret using correlation id as the key for uniqueness and not having to pass along to next function. In subsequent functions, that correlation id should be available in context. Use it to retrieve the token.

Comment: Thats not answering the question. The single jwt is stored on the client (like jwt is supposed to be).  Then that code is in the backend side,I don't see where would be the security issue of storing the jwt for the duration of the http call.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question then. It sounded like you wanted to store a client's JWT in your backend as a global variable accessible by multiple functions. That does have potential security issues depending on how it is handled. Using it to create a ClaimsPrincipal is better than storing the JWT from a risk perspective. Storing it in a shared cache (Key Vault/Redis, etc) with short expiration can be okay but still has risk. Some of that can be mitigated by ensuring it is encrypted when stored. Basically, anytime you store client credentials you add risk. Concurrency, attack vector..